# Laravel 5.5 middleware does not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I have middleware called `IsAdmin`, here is the code for it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class IsAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        if ($user->role === 10)
        {
            Session::flash('error', 'Трябва да сте администратор за да видите тази страница.');
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

here is registering it in the kernel:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'isadmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin::class,
    ];
}
```

and here is how I am protecting the routes in the controllers:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['auth', 'isadmin']);
}
```

the `auth` middleware works just fine.

The `isadmin` middleware stopped working when I changed the permission field I use in the database, on the user model. It used to be "$user->is_admin" and I've changed it to "$user->role" now even reverting back to the old way doesn't fix the problem.

Here is also the migration for the User model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->tinyInteger('role')->default(0);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Here are also my routes or `web.php` file:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'ReportController@home')->name('home');
Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');

Route::resource('/obekti', 'ObektiController');
Route::resource('/entrances', 'EntrancesController');
Route::resource('/apartments', 'ApartmentsController');
Route::resource('/people', 'PeopleController');
Route::resource('/boardmembers', 'BoardMembersController');
Route::resource('/companies', 'CompaniesController');

Route::get('/apartments/{id}/people', 'ApartmentsController@people');
Route::get('/entrances/{id}/apartments', 'EntrancesController@apartments');
Route::get('/obekti/{id}/entrances', 'ObektiController@entrances');
Route::get('/obekti/{id}/boardmembers', 'ObektiController@boardMembers');

Route::post('/search', 'HomeController@search');
```

Comment: Could you post your route? And I think middleware should be written on route file.

Comment: try adding middleware inside $middleware = [ ]

Comment: @lighter I've posted my routes. You can add middleware directly to your controllers that worked before for me.

Comment: @Wellwisher what and where is $middleware

Comment: Inside kernel you can find the `protected $middleware = []`

Comment: @Wellwisher I added IsAdmin to it, it didn't work.

Comment: how are you checking it? try to return something without any logic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173296/discussion-between-wellwisher-and-petar-vasilev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this line:

```
if ($user->role === 10)
```

it should've been this:

```
if ($user->role === 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are including your middleware inside `$routeMiddleware` property then you can use the middleware method to assign middleware to a route:

try this

```
Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@dashboard')->name('dashboard')->middleware(['isadmin','auth']);
```

or you can use the group method

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['isadmin', 'auth']], function () {
    //
});
```

Comment: I tried Route::resource('/obekti', 'ObektiController')->middleware('isadmin') it still didn't work